# Не получается изменить атрибут height через медиа-запрос

Tags: css, height

Имеется следующий код
`<section class="oportunities"></section>`

```
.oportunities {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1800px;
    }
```

Задача в том чтобы значение атрибута min-height изменить через медиа-запрос.

```
     @media (max-width: 991px){
    
    .oportunities{
     min-height: 1600px;
}
    }
```

Это не работает. Если заменить изначально атрибут min-height на height в css и затем в медиа-запросе манипулировать им, результат также нулевой.
Через медиа-запросы нельзя менять высоту блока?

Comment: Опортюнитиес)))00нулик. Хз чё так ору с этого слова 

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось проще.
Медиа запросы нужно ставить в конце файла со стилями а не в начале, в противном случае основные стили перезаписывают те которые прописаны в медиа запросах